# Timing for slow-absorbtion protein ingestion

Tags: workout, protein, muscle-mass, protein-shakes

It is known that you need to have good timing when eating protein, because this way you'll maximize muscle gain. But the problem is that I can only take albumin (no whey protein), and it is a slow absorption protein. So what if I take it before training? As it takes about 2 hours to be absorbed, would it be more efficient to take it before or after training??

Comment: "It is known that you need to have good timing when eating protein" no it isn't. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3577439/pdf/1550-2783-10-5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Timing your protein is a theory that I've read has been debunked many times over.  You'll still hear this being said from even the most seasoned lifters stuck in their ways, but ultimately it doesn't matter.  The most important factor is to ensure you're consuming the proper amount of protein.

If you're really headstrong on protein timing, then I'd say the logic seems sound that if you're taking a slow absorbing protein and you want it to start absorbing after your workout, you should take it before/during the workout to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

Timings won't matter as long as you are taking required amount of protein, also protein is very important post workout, if you can't take whey then you can try taking plant protein post workout, you need to try out different proteins to see which protein actually suits your body.
Just make sure your body is getting protein immediately  post workout. Rest as said, timings doesn't matter