Best time to take proteins in a trek
I am planning a trek of 10-15 days soon.
I would be walking morning to evening on high altitudes.
For protein and iron I am carrying tinned sardines. For protein I would also have nuts.
I am planning one can of sardines a day.
What would be the best time to eat that can? In breakfast when I am fresh, or in dinner after miles of walking and feeling exhausted? I generally workout in the morning and after workout eat my protein, and in the night I stay light. But this Trekking workout doesn't end till the night. What to do?

I’d be concerned that a ton of sardines and some nuts wouldn’t be enough protein. What your target grams per day?

@ThomasMarkov I think "kown" protein intake worth 3 eggs should be enough? I am planning to carry a dehydrated rice porridge for breakfast which would have peanuts, then lunch maybe something similar with dry fruits and jaggery, and later dinner of rice, lentils and some veges with sardines. Sounds good? I might be walking as much as 20-25 kms per day on high altitudes with 25-30 kg rucksack. I am 5'7" with 60kg body weight. I don't want to add too much rucksack weight either. I chose sardines because they have iron besides protein.

Probably doesn't matter https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/32682/timing-for-slow-absorbtion-protein-ingestion

Please define "high altitude".  That can mean something different to most people.

@AmazonDiesInDarkness I am planning visiting Everest Base Camp

For those not familiar, that means about 5150 meters - 5364 meters, depending on which popular Everest base camp (North, South respectively).

@AmazonDiesInDarkness this would be the Nepal base camp. I plan to start the trek from Jiri which is 1905 meters, and reach EBC which is altitude of 5364 meters.

Enjoy! You're probably experienced, but in case you aren't, remember that it's not only the altitude that will affect your body... it's the rapid change in altitude.

@AmazonDiesInDarkness got it, thanks.

At high altitude (to me high altitude is above about 5000meters/15000ft), eat as much as you can when you can.
Your digestive system is basically shut down most of the time lack of oxygen.  Because of this lack of oxygen, especially when walking is consuming everything you get, I would suggest plan on eating protein at the end of the day and your body can digest it while at rest.
When I was climbing at 6000+ meters we had days we were running deficits of over 2500cal a day. Even rest days we worked out were running a deficit even though we were basically forcing food into our mouths. Don't worry about what it is - protein/fat/carbs, it is calories, and you need as much as you can get. Staying hydrated is also very hard and incredibly important. With everything else your body is going though, meeting some arbitrary recommended protein intake will be the least of your worries.
